# Unable to connect My Flutter App to firebase analytics

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I am trying to connect and log events log using firebase analytics but there is no progress, I already have intergrated firebase google signin methods but not able to do so with firebase analytics.
Here are all the chnages i have done till now
added

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
```

in app level build.gradle in dependencies
also have firebase and firebase_analytics package install, i am still unable to log events

Answer (score 1):

in android/app/build.gradle add

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

````
//Firebase
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.2.2')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'```
````

in android/build.gradle add

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
```

in pubspec.yaml add

```
firebase_core: ^2.7.0
firebase_analytics: ^10.1.4
```

here sample demo

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:firebase_analytics/firebase_analytics.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyRouteObserver extends RouteObserver<PageRoute<dynamic>> {
  @override
  void didPush(Route route, Route? previousRoute) async {
    if(route.settings.name.toString().toLowerCase().replaceAll("/", "").isNotEmpty){
      await FirebaseAnalytics.instance.logEvent(
        name: Platform.isIOS
            ? "ios_${route.settings.name.toString().toLowerCase().replaceAll("/", "")}"
            : route.settings.name.toString().toLowerCase().replaceAll("/", ""),
        parameters: {},
      );
    }

    super.didPush(route, previousRoute);
  }
}
```

in lib/main.dart add in this line inside MaterialApp

```
navigatorObservers: [MyRouteObserver()],
```

Don't forget to initialize Firebase

```
await Firebase.initializeApp();
```

Answer (score 0):

in android/app/build.gradle add

```
id "com.google.gms.google-services"
```

in android/build.gradle add

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
```

in main.dart

```dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  try {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    FirebaseAnalytics.instance.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
  } catch (e) {
    print("Failed to initialize Firebase: $e");
  }

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```